# Extract date from XML file and move file to directory created from date

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory that contains close to a million XML files. Needless to say, it takes forever to load (20+ minutes) So, I'm writing a script to divide the files into folders with the top level being year and having months under each year. There are 4 main filenames where the date can be extracted from the 3rd token and the rest from the second token. ie:

```
BA1253570001_BALMIS_20130617_TRC_0_109506738E.xml
BA1254260001_ACCTV21_20140430_AMR_0_1095611492.xml
BA1736330001_SWFTOUT_20140929_LIQ_1_MTBX553494.xml
BA1739240001_FEDOUT_20140904_LIQ_1_105633316M.xml
```

The rest are like this:

```
EODMESS_20140718_MTBX473286.xml
MSGCONF_20140410_109558667V.xml
```

I'm sure there is an easier way to do it, but here is my code so far:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "starttime=%time%"
pushd C:\temp\xmls
for /f %%a in ('dir /b/o:d *.xml') do (
  call :ExtractDates %%a ret
  echo %%a - !ret!
  for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ("!ret!") do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%c in ("%%b") do (
        if not exist .\%%e md .\%%e
        if not exist .\%%e\%%c md .\%%e\%%c
        if %%b equ %%c/%%d/%%e (
        echo moving %%~nxa to .\%%e\%%c
        echo move %%~nxa .\%%e\%%c
        pause
        )
    )   
  )
)
echo Start time: %starttime%
echo End time: %time% 
popd
exit /b

:ExtractDates
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Echo Starting ExtractDates
for %%a in (BALMIS ACCTV21 FEDOUT SWFTOUT) do (
  if not errorlevel 1 (set t=3) else set t=2
  Call :ExtractFunc %~1 %%a !t! ret
  endlocal&set "%~2=!ret!"&exit /b 0
)  
exit /b

:ExtractFunc
@echo on 
setlocal
Echo Starting ExtractFunc
for /f "tokens=%3 delims=_" %%a in (
    'echo %~1^|Findstr "%~2"'
    ) do ( 
    if not errorlevel 1 (
      endlocal&set "%~4=%%a"&exit /b 0
    ) 
)  
exit /b
```

The problem is that the variable token isn't returning the right number and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*_*.xml" '
 ) DO SET "filename=%%a"&CALL :process

POPD

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR /f "tokens=2,3,6delims=_" %%m IN ("%filename%") DO SET "date1=%%m"&SET "date2=%%n"&SET "whichdate=%%o"
IF DEFINED whichdate SET "date1=%date2%"
IF NOT DEFINED date2 GOTO :eof
ECHO(MD .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%
ECHO(MOVE "%filename%" .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%\
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Simply extract the two possible datestrings and use the presence of the sixth token to signal which of the two positions to select for generation of the destination directory. Skip if there's no third token (fails to fit mask specified)

Then select the required field to `date1` and do some substringing.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. Your code is much more concise than mine and with a few little tweaks, it runs quite a bit faster.