# Spinner with update for every 1000 files moved

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code for a spinner that I found somewhere long ago. I'm trying to figure out how to modify it so it displays an update for every 1000 files moved. So, it would look like this:

```
 Moving XML Files...|  1,000 Files moved
 Moving XML Files.../  2,000 Files moved
 Moving XML Files...-  3,000 Files moved
 Moving XML Files...\  4,000 Files moved
```

Where the spinner chars continue to move. I'll be running this on close to a million files, so I really need to have an indication of what the status is. Any help or suggestions of a better way is greatly appreciated.

**CODE**

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :SpinnerEx
exit /b


:SpinnerEx
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

FOR /L %%n in (1,1,50) DO (
    call :spinner
    ping localhost -n 1 > nul
)
exit /b

:spinner
set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
set "spinChars=\|/-"
<nul set /p ".=Moving XML Files...!spinChars:~%spinner%,1!!CR!"
exit /b
```

And [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699148/extract-date-from-xml-file-and-move-file-to-directory-created-from-date) is the code to actually do the moving provided by Magoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Magoo's script, I'd replace the

```js
) DO SET "filename=%%a"&CALL :process
```

with

```js
) DO (
    SET "filename=%%a"&CALL :process
    rem increment file counter
    rem if total divided by 1000 has no remainder, advance the spinner
)
```

Something like this:

```js
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "spinChars=\|/-"
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
SET "filesmoved=0"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

set /P "=Moving XML Files...%spinChars:~0,1%  0 Files moved"<NUL

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*_*.xml" '
 ) DO (
    SET "filename=%%a"&CALL :process
    set /a filesmoved += 1, thousand = filesmoved %% 1000
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if !thousand! equ 0 call :spinner
    endlocal
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR /f "tokens=2,3,6delims=_" %%m IN ("%filename%") DO SET "date1=%%m"&SET "date2=%%n"&SET "whichdate=%%o"
IF DEFINED whichdate SET "date1=%date2%"
IF NOT DEFINED date2 GOTO :eof
ECHO(MD .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%
ECHO(MOVE "%filename%" .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%\
GOTO :EOF

:spinner
set "moved=%filesmoved%"
:spinner2
if %filesmoved% geq 4000 set /a filesmoved -= 4000 & goto :spinner2
set /a spinpos = filesmoved / 1000
for /L %%I in (1,1,50) do set /P "=%BS%"<NUL
set /P "=Moving XML Files...!spinChars:~%spinPos%,1!  %moved% Files moved"<NUL
goto :EOF
```

The `for /f... ("prompt $H...")` line captures a backspace character to a variable (to `%BS%`).  The `for /L %%I in (1,1,50)` line backspaces 50 times.  Hopefully the rest is fairly self-explanatory.

If you'd like to test the logic without actually moving any files, here's the same script with the file iteration loop replaced with a simple `for /L` loop:

```js
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "spinChars=\|/-"
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
SET "filesmoved=0"

set /P "=Moving XML Files...%spinChars:~0,1%  0 Files moved"<NUL

for /L %%I in (1,1,50000) do (
    set /a filesmoved += 1, thousand = filesmoved %% 1000
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if !thousand! equ 0 call :spinner
    endlocal    
)

goto :EOF

:spinner
set "moved=%filesmoved%"
:spinner2
if %filesmoved% geq 4000 set /a filesmoved -= 4000 & goto :spinner2
set /a spinpos = filesmoved / 1000
for /L %%I in (1,1,50) do set /P "=%BS%"<NUL
set /P "=Moving XML Files...!spinChars:~%spinPos%,1!  %moved% Files moved"<NUL
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks Rojo, this is perfect. I haven't worked with batch scripting for over a year and I'm a bit rusty. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't run the spinner the whole time. It is just changing when the Files moved gets updated. Easy fix? thanks

Comment: Not an easy one, no.  You might ought to copypaste my "Something like this" code block to a new question.  I'm geting ready to head out for the evening, and probably won't be back till Friday or possibly next week, depending on this evening's weather.  If your new question goes unanswered for a day or two, reply here and give me the link and I'll see what I can do when I get a chance.  `:)`